# Call google maps api out of a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Till now I have integrated my google maps-api with this code:

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLEKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

And in the function `initMap`, I had my latitude and longitude.

But now, I get my latitude and longitude out of a database with an onclick-ajax-script on a button.

Which means, that wenn my site gets loaded I get this error:

```
InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

Because there is no lat and lng right now.

I need to load the initMap function in the onclick-function of the button. Can someone tell me how to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `&callback=initMap`. Than you can initialize the map from whereever you want.